# Image Processing (need pixel value of an image)

Tags: android

I want to make an app, in which I want to take a picture and input x,y axis it will show me corresponding point pixel value from the captured picture .

I don't have any knowledge about image processing well . So, how can I do it ? help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past is by writing the image to the filesystem and then decoding it. Admittedly its a little inefficient but it's functional.

This requires a number of steps. I suggest you read over this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath). It describes the process of taking an image and saving it to the file system which you will need to do **before** you can do the rest of these steps.

Next you will need to use `BitmapFactory` to decode the image which will give you an instance of `Bitmap` which you can do all sorts of things with (documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)). In this example I return the `Color` object for the pixel located at `(50, 50)` using `getPixel()`. This example assumes that the path the the image is `mCurrentPhotoPath` but should be wherever you saved the image.

```
private Color getColor() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    return bitmap.getPixel(50, 50);
}
```

You can get RGB values from this `Color` object which is what I think you are wanting to do. That can be found under the `Color` object documentation on Android Developers as well.